# Can I extend my MacBook Air 13.3 A1369 SSD to 512GB?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, ssd

So the question in the title “Can I extend my MacBook Air 13.3 A1369 SSD to 512GB?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes http://eshop.macsales.com/search/MBA2011.480

You will need to reinstall the OS onto that drive or clone your current drive to it.